# c# ListView not updating when Property Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, inotifypropertychanged

My UI is not updating when more data is added to the ObservableCollection.  The console output says A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred.  Should I be using Inotifycollectionchanged instead?  Here is some of the code:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static d:GrabUserConversationModel._Conversation}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged">
```

UserConversationModel.cs

```
public class UserConversationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserConversationModel()
    {
    }

    public string Name
    { get; set; }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string Obj)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Obj));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow 
{

    static GrabUserConversationModel grabUserConversationModel;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...

    }

  static void AddData()
    {
   grabUserConversationModel.Conversation.Add(new UserConversationModel { Name = "TestName" });

    }
```

GrabUserConversationModel.cs

```
class GrabUserConversationModel
{

    public static ObservableCollection<UserConversationModel> _Conversation = new ObservableCollection<UserConversationModel>();


    public ObservableCollection<UserConversationModel> Conversation
    {
        get { return _Conversation; }
        set { _Conversation = value; }
    }
     ...
```

Comment: Try removing your `UpdateSourceTrigger` set on the binding. Let WPF hook the collection and catch collection changes like it would normally by default.

Answer (score 0):

your property `ObservableCollection<UserConversationModel> Conversation` is not implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public ObservableCollection<UserConversationModel> Conversation
{
    get { return _Conversation; }
    set { _Conversation = value; OnPropertyChanged("Conversation");}
}
```

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: obviously I meant using it's method OnPropertyChanged :)

Comment: The problem with this solution as it curently stands though is if you look at his binding, he is not binding to that property, but to the static field instead.

Comment: in the more general scope the problem is not working on a MVVM pattern :)

Comment: on that binding... the name of the property is wrong i think (you're binding to the field not to the property)

Comment: I had the binding previously as ItemsSource='{Binding Conversation}' but thought because GrabUserConversationModel is static, it needed to be the way it is above.